# Using spiwer cannot slide over input area

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I develop a mobile webpage and I use the swiper.js to achieve slide between 2 pages. But every page has some input textfield for users input their username and passwd. And I found the swiper become useless over input area, but it is normal in other area like button and so on. Now, I want to achieve that if I click on the input area, then I can input something I want, but if I want to slide the page, I can also slide anywhere I want.

Comment: Please edit your question with code samples so that others can help review what you've tried so far.